# FATAL: no indexes found in '/home/XXXX/searchengine/config/development.sphinx.conf'

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, thinking-sphinx

sphinx show me this error when i want to ( rake ts:start )
im using rails 5.1.4 and ruby 2.4.1

```
Sphinx 2.2.9-id64-release (rel22-r5006)
Copyright (c) 2001-2015, Andrew Aksyonoff
Copyright (c) 2008-2015, Sphinx Technologies Inc (http://sphinxsearch.com)
using config file '/home/snoura/searchengine/config/development.sphinx.conf'...
FATAL: no indexes found in '/home/snoura/searchengine/config/development.sphinx.conf'

The Sphinx start command failed:
Command: searchd --pidfile --config "/home/snoura/searchengine/config/development.sphinx.conf"
Status:  1
Output:  See above

There may be more information about the failure in /home/snoura/searchengine/log/development.searchd.log.
```

this is what i have in my model Post.rb

```
define_index do
indexes content
indexes :name, sortable: true
end
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. I'm not highly familiar with sphinx but I'll have a shot at getting some more info in case it can be helpful for solving your problem. The error message says there might be more info in: `/home/snoura/searchengine/log/development.searchd.log` what's in there? Also the error message talks about no indexes in: `'/home/snoura/searchengine/config/development.sphinx.conf'` what is in there instead?

Comment: Also, googling showed me this: https://github.com/pat/thinking-sphinx/issues/937 I don't know if it'll help you but have you tried that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things to note here.

First: you're using a *very* old syntax for defining indices (Taryn's comment on your question is spot on). `define_index` within a model is the approach of Thinking Sphinx v1/v2. Thinking Sphinx v3 (which is the version that supports Rails 3.2 through to 5.x) expects index definitions to live within the `app/indices` directory. So, you'll want to add a file there (perhaps `post_index.rb`) which contains the following:

```
ThinkingSphinx::Index.define :post, :with => :active_record do
  indexes content
  indexes name, sortable: true
end
```

The full index definition syntax is available in the documentation:
https://freelancing-gods.com/thinking-sphinx/indexing.html

The second thing to note is that you need to have your indices processed before starting the daemon. This means running `rake ts:index`.